# OnClickListener only works on first ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I am learning to write Android Apps right now and got quite a dumb problem.
I´ve got a recyclerview with a bunch of viewholders inside and now, when it is clicked on one, I want to remove it, so obviously I´d remove the item, that the viewholder is displaying (so the object represented rather then the holder itself) and notify the recyclerview of the changes. 
So now I thought I managed to set an onclickListener on the ItemView as soon as the ViewHolder is created, but somehow it always just removes the first element and when I want to remove another one I need to pause the app, so the viewholders are generated again. So it also removes, when I click on another holder than the first, but always the uppest item in the list.

So here is my code of the Viewholder:

```
 class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Some textViews
        public RowData item;
        public RecycleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final RowData item) {
            super(itemView);
            //Assign textViews in the itemView to variables
            this.item = item;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RemoveItem(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And the above RemoveItem(Rowdata data) method is a method in my Adapter:

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.RecycleViewHolder> {
    private List<RowData> items;
    public RecycleAdapter(List<RowData> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view,viewGroup,false);
        return new RecycleViewHolder(view, items.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleViewHolder recycleViewHolder, int i) {
        RowData actualData = items.get(i);
        //Set texts in textViews
        recycleViewHolder.item = actualData;
    }

    public void RemoveItem(RowData item) {
        items.remove(item);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I don´t know, if you need the xml, but it is just a standard xml file, with a constraint layout in it and three textviews in the layout. The layout has no id, so I just used:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view,viewGroup,false);
```

But I doubt that´s the problem.

Comment: pass item position to view holder class and remove the item  at that position

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
 RemoveItem(RecycleViewHolder.this.item);
```

And not:

```
RemoveItem(item);
```

The reason is that you copy the variable item into the clickListener object, and you never change it.

[Here is a link to a github project with your code and my answer.](https://github.com/uriel-frankel/RecyclerViewHolder)